# Set language of browser for link expansion in Slack

Tags: localization, slack

If I type in `http://lang-8.com/` into a [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) chat room on the web version, it comes up with Japanese language text, presumably because that's the default for that web site:

> http://lang-8.com/
>
> Lang-8
>
> Multi-lingual language learning and language exchange Lang-8
>
> Lang-8は世界190ヶ国以上のユーザーが集まり、多言語学習と異文化交流を行う無料サイトです。Lang-8では異なる母語を持つユーザー同士が、お互いに言語を教え合い交流しています。

By contrast, if I visit the site in a web browser, the site's content is in English.

Is it possible to tell Slack to indicate it speaks English when visiting a web site for link expansion? If so, how do I configure that?